# JavaScriptSerializer issue parsing deserialized json

Tags: c#, json

I have the following program where I am trying to extract a specific value from a WebRequest response sent in json utilizing javascriptserializer to parse the values. Below is the code:

```
       public class Self
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class Xframe
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class Links
    {
        public Self self { get; set; }
        public User user { get; set; }
        public Xframe xframe { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Links _links { get; set; }
    }


    public class Foo
    {
        public Foo() { objects = new List<RootObject>(); }
        public Links Self { get; set; }
        public Links User { get; set; }
        public Links Xframe { get; set; }
        public List<RootObject> objects { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string sURL;
            sURL = "<replacing value>";
            WebRequest wrGETURL;
            wrGETURL = WebRequest.Create(sURL);
            Stream objStream;
            objStream = wrGETURL.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(objStream);

            string sLine = "";
            string uLine = "";

                sLine = objReader.ReadLine();
                if (sLine != null)
                    uLine = sLine;
                    //Console.WriteLine(uLine);

                JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                Foo foo = ser.Deserialize<Foo>(uLine);
                Console.WriteLine(foo);
```

When I try to write the foo output and view the properties of the foo object, all properties are null. I believe my issues is in the class Foo but I can't seem to understand what I am missing. Any help will be much appreciated. I used jsontocsharp to create the classes for the deserialized json string.

Comment: 1) What does the JSON (the entire contents of `objStream`) look like?  2) What does `uLine` look like?  3) Why are you parsing only a single line of the response?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When sending a GET request to https://lyncdiscover.microsoft.com, it returns the below response:

{"_links":{"self":{"href":"https://lync32.lyncweb.microsoft.com/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root?ori
ginalDomain=microsoft.com"},"user":{"href":"https://lync32.lyncweb.microsoft.com/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverSer
vice.svc/root/oauth/user?originalDomain=microsoft.com"},"xframe":{"href":"https://lync32.lyncweb.microsoft.co
m/Autodiscover/XFrame/XFrame.html"}}}

Comment: I am only needing to grab a single line to pass to another class to send back an appropriate REST PUT command. I determined I could actual see it was parsing correctly by making the following changes:

 JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
 RootObject link2 = ser.Deserialize<RootObject>(uLine);
 Console.WriteLine(link2._links.self.href);

This allowed me to see the specific parameter I needed. Ultimately this will work, but I was hoping to store each of the values in a list so I could recall each one at different stages in the code.

Comment: So, have you answered the question yourself, or is there still a question?  If you're looking for a serializer that can perform on-the-fly data mapping, `JavaScriptSerializer` isn't it.  Consider Json.NET or maybe `DataContractJsonSerializer` instead.

Comment: I am mainly needing to rewrite the Foo class to properly store all elements of the individual classes so I can reference later. I am only able to directly work with the Links class, but was hoping to consolidate all of the classes that reference the deserialized json response into a single class called Foo to work with that moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing the data as a JSON object allowed me to do what I needed.

Comment: SInce it is old question, more details are always better. How did it solve OP's & your problem?